# Query ADAM/ADLDS for disabled accounts

Tags: .net, active-directory

I am trying to use the DirectorySearcher from .Net to query for disabled users.

I am using a fairly fast list function very similar to the one posted here.
[Enumerating Large Groups With Active Directory](http://www.netid.washington.edu/documentation/enumeratingLargeGroups.aspx).

I have tried changing the filter to

`(&(objectCategory=person)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`

I get no results. It seems that I cannot use the DirectorySearcher in this manor. Has anyone done anything like this. I just need basic info and would prefer a lightweight/fast query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, introduced in .NET 3.5, things like that become a lot easier.

Read all about it here: [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

You would first have to establish a context for your operations - AD LDS is explicitly supported:

```
// create a context for an AD LDS store pointing to the 
// partition root using the credentials for a user in the AD LDS store 
// and SSL for encryption
PrincipalContext ldsContext = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, "sea-dc-02.fabrikam.com:50001", 
    "ou=ADAM Users,o=microsoft,c=us", 
    ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind, 
    "CN=administrator,OU=ADAM Users,O=Microsoft,C=US ", "pass@1w0rd01");
```

and then you'd create a `PrincipalSearcher` and define in a "query-by-example" style what you're looking for:

```
// create a principal object representation to describe
// what will be searched 
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ldsContext);

// define the properties of the search (this can use wildcards)
user.Enabled = false;
user.Name = "user*";

// create a principal searcher for running a search operation
PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();

// assign the query filter property for the principal object you created
// you can also pass the user principal in the PrincipalSearcher constructor
pS.QueryFilter = user;

// run the query
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();

Console.WriteLine("Disabled accounts starting with a name of 'user':");
foreach (Principal result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}", result.Name);
}
```

Pretty nifty, eh?? If you ever can - use the new `S.DS.AM` namespace!!

Comment: cool. I was still stuck in LDAP land. Do you know off hand if this will suffer from the same account limitations as the old queries? 1000 or 1500.

Comment: @Hal Diggs: see the [MSDN docs for PrincipalSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.aspx) - it says the default page size is 256 KB of data, but it can be set to be something else.

Comment: to answer my own comment, yeah the **PrincipleSearcher does have a 1000 limit** but you can get around it by contructing the PrincipleSearcher using the UserPrincipal as a parameter **PrincipleSearcher(UserPrincipal)**, this seems to allow 1000+ results. Odd that I never saw this commented on MSDN.